# How to pause my SpriteKit game when Notification pops up?

Tags: swift, notifications, sprite-kit, pause

I have a problem when I get a banner notification such as a text message while my game is running. It freezes my app for a second on the first text banner notification and skips forward when it unfreezes. I was wondering if there was a way to pause the game when a notification like this occurs during my game?

Comment: this is answered and discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291897/pausing-ios-game-when-notification-center-control-center-is-launched